# How can I educate myself about the human body to be able to come up with useful exercises

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, exercise-technique, personal-training

I know that personal trainers are usually well educated about the human body so that they know which exercise engages which groups of muscle. They often have very good awareness of how to use your surroundings the same way as gym equipment. For example, a park bench can be used for elevated push-ups, etc.

I am not completely clueless about our muscle groups and types of exercises, I can also deduce what the effect of a particular exercise is. I would like to educate myself further though.

Which resources should I use to study this particular topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExRx.net](http://exrx.net)

I cannot think of a better resource to learn about every exercise ever thought up. Most "new" exercises are variations on these.

Comment: A lovely website, thank you! I was looking for something like this :).